# How to redirect in django along with the request object

Tags: ajax, django

I am facing a problem regarding the redirects in django.I am using an ajax call to login and in return i am getting a json on failure and on success a template.

But On Success the response is getting rendered as html instead it should redirect to home page using `render_to_response`.

## i tried

Using `HttpResponseRedirect` i don't get a request object and hence i can't get the session parameter which is my requirement.

## Note: This might have some typos as i renamed some variables for confidentiality.

## View

```
def sign_in(request):
    """
    :param request: data(json)
    """
    response_data = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "Request Landed"
        data = request.POST.get('data', None)
        data = json.loads(data)
        username = data.get("username", None)
        password = data.get("password", None)
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                auth.login(request, user)
                context = RequestContext(request)
                context_dict = {}
                request.session['username'] = username
                request.session['dd_id'] = str(P.objects.get(username=username).dd_id)
                return render_to_response("p/home.html", context_dict, context)
            else:
                response_data = json.dumps({'status': 'NOT OK', 'reason_phrase': 'Account confirmation is pending at '
                                                                                 'your end.Please check your email '
                                                                                 'address for confirmation link.'})
        else:
            response_data = json.dumps({'status': 'NOT OK', 'reason_phrase': 'Invalid Credentials!'})
    else:
        response_data = json.dumps({'status': 'NOT OK', 'reason_phrase': 'Invalid Request type!'})
    return generate_response(response_data=response_data)
```

## Update

I used a ajax request and sent a redirect on failure for a json to show invalid details error and render_to_response in case of success.Failure works fine but on success i am seing the template that is being sent by render_to_response on the same page....How to cope with that..

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it is rendered as HTML is because you have used `render_to_response` ...that's what it does :)

So instead of this:

```
return render_to_response("p/home.html", context_dict, context)
```

you should do:

```
return redirect('home')
```

where `'home'` is the name of the url to your homepage view in `urls.py`

you'll need this import at the top of your view file:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
```

in your home view you will have access to a request object and session data that you need

Comment: But how will i get access to session variable in home as i am not sending request object in it ?

Comment: what happens is Django returns an http redirect response _to the user's browser_, which then initiates a new request to the redirect url... so there is no problem, your home view will receive a `request` object

Comment: Okay so that means redirect will goto urls.py and maps to the home view and hence hit the def home (request): return render_to_response so now ill get the request object ?

Comment: Can you help me again got a problem

Comment: I updated the question ,see if you can understand it

Comment: You need to think through what you _want_ to happen, there is no point rendering a template response if you don't want to display it. If you just want an empty success response you can do `return HttpResponse(status_code=204)` in your Django view (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#204)

Comment: I dont want to print blank response.But as i said i want to redirect to a new page in success ,i used redirect but it did not work.The response is being shown on the same page

Comment: That's because it was an ajax request. The point of an ajax request is that the current page doesn't change. If you want to change the page, but only on success, then you will need to check the content of the response in javascript and change the page in javascript (by setting `location.href`)

Comment: But if I redirect using js.I am not getting access to session variables as I did not get the request object.

Comment: have you tried it? because that's not true: any request to a Django view, whether normal, ajax or by javascript location.href, will result in a `request` object with session info being passed to your view function

Comment: It worked now.the problem i overlooked was i used render to response without the request object so thasy could not access the params. Thanks again